# import from base component can't find variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created one BaseComponent which will be extended in all other components :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, Image, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class BaseComponent extends Component {

}
```

And in my other components i am using it like :

```
import BaseComponent from '../Components/BaseComponent'

export default class LoginScreen extends BaseComponent {

}
```

Now i have imported `View`,`ScrollView` etc in BaseComponent but when i am trying to use it in child component, it is showing error that `can'find variable View`.

How can i use imported class of BaseComponnet in ChildComponent?

Comment: You need to import them again in your LoginScreen,

Answer (score 2):

In Nodejs each file is a treated as a module, that has its own scope of variables. When you import variable into file say `React or ScrollView` for example, you add this variable to the module scope, but not to the global scope.

In case of `webpack` you can use `ProvidePlugin` to a few imports as global

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  React: 'react' // ReactJS module name in node_modules folder
})
```

After that you are able to skip importing these variables variable in all of your modules as `webpack` will do it itself handle it whereever needed.